# How to postpone an update in a WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

From .NET 4.5, the BindingBase class now contains a `Delay` property. This enables to set an integer that represents the number of milliseconds that the Framework will wait before updating a data source. However, I want the Framework to wait before updating the UserControl. In other words, I am looking for a way to achieve something similar to the `Delay` Property, but the *other way round*.

In my particular case, I have a TextBox bound to a Double value. Since the source changes rapidly, the user cannot spot the values in the TextBox.

I thought about implementing a Filter into an implementation of `IValueConverter`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because I have several TextBoxes arranged in a ListBox. Since all of them use the same ValueConverter-Object, I cannot store a queue of previous values into that ValueConverter.

Is there a general way to filter the Text Property of a WPF TextBox, so that the user can actually *see* the content when source values change very quickly?

Comment: You can bind the TextBox to another propery of your ViewModel that raises PropertyChanged less frequently but use the existing property as backing storage.

Comment: Without going into too much detail, one possibility to look at is the possibility of using RX, and ReactiveCommand, and using a delay on the binding through that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case, you could use a `Stopwatch` to skip certain changes.

```
private readonly Stopwatch _watch;
private double _yourValue;

public Ctor()
{
    _watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
}

public double YourValue
{
    get { return _yourValue; }
    set
    {
        if (Math.Abs(value - _yourValue) < Double.Epsilon) return;
        // Always save value
        _yourValue = value;
        // Only trigger notification after a certain amount of time 
        // (e.g. once every second)
        if (_watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1000)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged();
            _watch.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @berti What's the issue with the answer/downvote? It correctly postpone the update in a WPF TextBox.

Comment: I have not downvoted this anwser (I do not even have enough repuatation points for downvoting anything...). Actually, I was thinking about doing something similar. Another way would be to use a DispacherTimer and keep a boolean `_isChanged` in the ViewModel. When the source changes, `_isChanged` is set to `true`. In the DispacherTimer's EventHandler, `OnPropertyChanged` is called and `_isChanged` is set back to `false`. ...I guess there are different ways to achieve this. However, I was hoping there would be a better one.

Comment: @berti My bad. Well, sadly there isn't a better way. If you get a lot and quick changes, and you want to _hide_ those changes for a certain **time**, there's no way you can do this without taking care of the **time** somewhere. :)